# Restar dias correctamente

Tags: java, date, calendar

Java me ofrece diferentes variables para restar dias a una fecha como lo son:

`DAY_OF_MONTH`
`DAY_OF_WEEK`
`DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`
`DAY_OF_YEAR`

Tengo un método en el que le restó días meses o años según deseo a una fecha, pero tengo dudas sobre cual de todos ellos usar para los días, y cual es la diferencia entre ellos, en el sentido de como me podria afectar en el funcionamiento, aqui les muestro el método del que les hablo

```
public Date SumaRestarFecha(Date fecha, int sumaresta, String opcion)
    {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        try
        {

            calendar.setTime(fecha);
            switch (opcion)
            {
                case "DAYS":
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, sumaresta);

                    break;

                case "MONTHS":
                    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, sumaresta);

                    break;

                case "YEARS":
                    calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, sumaresta);

                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("parametro enviado al Switch no concuerda");
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error:\n" + e);
        }
        return calendar.getTime();
    }
```

cabe mencionar que si quiero que sume, `sumaresta` será un número mayor que cero, si quiero que reste será menor que cero.

¿Está bien utilizar el `DAY_OF_WEEK` para lo que deseo? y si no ¿cual seria el indicado y porque?

Comment: Aquí tienes algo de lo que buscas: http://developando.com/blog/java-sumar-restar-horas-dias-fecha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para lo que estas comentando la opción seria DAY_OF_MONTH porque DAY_OF_WEEK indica que día de la semana que es Lunes, Martes, miércoles... y si le sumas o restas te indicara en que día de la semana te quedas pero no te será útil porque no tendrás la referencia para la fecha.

Answer (score 4):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Date now = c.getTime();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -15);
Date nowMinus15 = c.getTime();

System.out.println("FECHA DE HOY: " + now + "  FECHA HACE 15 DÍAS:  "+nowMinus15);
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo apropiado, java8, sería que utilizaras las clases del paquete java.time

Por ejemplo:

```
    public Date SumaRestarFecha(Date fecha, int sumaresta, String opcion){
        LocalDate date = fecha.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        //Con Java9
        //LocalDate date = LocalDate.ofInstant(input.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        TemporalUnit unidadTemporal;
        switch(opcion){
            case "DAYS":
                unidadTemporal = ChronoUnit.DAYS;
                break;
            case "MONTHS":
                unidadTemporal = ChronoUnit.MONTHS;
                break;
            case "YEARS":
                unidadTemporal = ChronoUnit.YEARS;
                break;
            default:
                //Controlar error
        }
        LocalDate dateResultado = date.minus(sumaresta, unidadTemporal);
        return Date.from(dateResultado.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    }
```

Comment: El método que me pones ahi me funcionaria de la misma forma? osea, si sumaresta fuera mayor que cero se sumará, y si fuera menor que cero se restará?

Comment: Eso es, así funciona.