# como calcular a partir de una fecha los días quincenales(15) y semanales(7)?

Tags: java

Buen dia, lo que tengo hasta el momento es lo siguiente:

```
int dia = dia + 15;
if(dia > 31){
```

/*AQUI RADICA MI INCONVENIENTE CUANDO TENGO QUE PASAR AL PROXIMO MES Y SEGUIR CALCULANDO LOS DIAS EN EL SIGUIENTE MES.*/

}

Desde ya Gracias

Comment: necesitas usar un tipo Date y hacer la cuenta con una instancia de Calendar fijate este hilo https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/94045/81450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Saludos, Jose Felix.

Podrías utilizar la clase [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) (si utilizas Java 8).

Esta clase ofrece métodos bastante útiles para sumar cierta cantidad de días, meses, semanas, años, entre otros... a partir de una fecha determinada.

Según indicas, quieres encontrar los días quincenales y semanales de una fecha `x`, supongamos que tenemos la fecha `10/04/2018` (10 de Abril del 2018):

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2018, 4, 10); // año, mes, día
```

El método `plusDays` nos sería conveniente para sumarle cierta cantidad de días a esa fecha, en nuestro caso, le sumaremos `15`:

```
date = date.plusDays(15);
// la fecha en este ejemplo fue sobreescrita
// en caso de necesitar ambas fechas solo crea una nueva instancia LocalDate
```

El resultado sería el siguiente:

```
2018-04-10 // <-- La fecha original
2018-04-25 // <-- Después de plusDays (15 días después)
```

Como se observa, el día 10 no se tomó en cuenta, esto porque `plusDays` comienza a contar desde el día siguiente (el día 11). En caso de necesitar el conteo "de hoy en 15", sólo resta 1 a la cantidad de días.

Otra ventaja de este método es que puedes sumarle los días aún si se encuentra el otro mes. Supongamos ahora que tenemos la fecha `25/04/2018` (25 de Abril del 2018):

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2018, 4, 25);
date = date.plusDays(15);
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
2018-04-25 // la fecha original
2018-05-10 // 15 días después
```

Como ves, el día número 15 a partir de la fecha original se encuentra en el otro mes. En el caso de los días semanales, podrías sumar `7` utilizando el método `plusDays` o sumar sólo 1 utilizando el método `plusWeeks`.

Si necesitas recuperar algún dato de la fecha, por ejemplo, si únicamente necesitas el día de esa fecha en entero y no en `LocalDate`, utiliza los métodos `get` de la clase `LocalDate`:

```
date.getDayOfMonth(); // retorna el día
date.getMonthValue(); // retorna el mes (en entero)
date.getYear(); // retorna el año
```

Comment: Gracias justo lo que necesitaba.