# error binary operator '-'

Tags: java

```
public void cambioFechaCompra(DetalleDocumentoDto detalle) {
  if (detalle.getCodFormaGeneracion().equals("1")) {
    detalle.setFechaCompra(new Date());
  } else if (detalle.getCodFormaGeneracion().equals("2")) {
    detalle.setFechaCompra(new Date(new Date().getTime() - 86400000 * 6));
  }
}
```

Me aparece este error error: `bad operand types for binary operator '-'` en este fragmento del código pero no sé cómo solucionarlo `((detalle.getFechaCompra() - diasRestar) == resta)` el código es para que valide que no se pueda seleccionar los anteriores 6 días de la fecha actual.

```
public long cambioFechaCompra(DetalleDocumentoDto detalle) {

  detalle.setFechaCompra(new Date());

  int diasRestar = 6;
  SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
  Date detalles = (Date) formatter.parse("11-January-2023");
  long mills = detalles.getTime();

  Date resta = detalle.getFechaCompra();

  if (detalle.getCodFormaGeneracion().equals("1")) {
    detalle.getFechaCompra();
    return mills;

  } else if (detalle.getCodFormaGeneracion().equals("2")) {
    if ((detalle.getFechaCompra() - diasRestar) == resta) {
      detalle.getFechaCompra();
      return mills;
    }
  }

  return mills;
}
```

Comment: Esa etiqueta js en tu pregunta no va, js es completamente diferente a java.

Comment: como la puedo colocar perdon

Comment: Ya lo edite yo, tranquilo.

Comment: @JoseMgz_Ux donde perdon? y que pena es que tengo que entregar esto casi que ya

Comment: O sea, yo edite la pregunta y las correcciones fueron aceptadas, si ves algunas cosas están diferentes y abajo del código solo está la etiqueta java, antes también estaba la de JavaScript allí, ahora estoy viendo tu código para ver si te ayudo con tu problema.

Comment: @JoseMgz_Ux a si que pena muchisimas gracias en verdad

Comment: Que trae `detalle.getFechaCompra()`?, una fecha?

Comment: la fecha actual @JoseMgz_Ux si no que lo setteo aca detalle.setFechaCompra(new Date());

Comment: Y cómo pretendes restar un objeto de tipo `Date` y uno de tipo `int`?? Qué resultado esperas de eso? A una piedra puedes restarle tres manzanas? Imagino que no, en Java es lo mismo. Restar números está bien... restar objetos, está complicado.

Comment: @Benito-B es que antes tenia este pedazo de codigo detalle.setFechaCompra(new Date(new Date().getTime()-86400000*6)); que me trae la fecha 6 dia antes pero a hora necesito que no se pueda seleccionar la fecha entre la actual y los -6 dias o que salga un error, y perdon es que nunca habia echo esto y me estoy guiando por tutoriales

Comment: Este era mi codigo antes @Benito-B
    public void cambioFechaCompra(DetalleDocumentoDto detalle) {
        if(detalle.getCodFormaGeneracion().equals("1")){
            detalle.setFechaCompra(new Date());
        }else if (detalle.getCodFormaGeneracion().equals("2")) {
            detalle.setFechaCompra(new Date(new Date().getTime()-86400000*6));
        }
        }

Comment: Si no me equivoco `detalle.getFechaCompra()` es un string y quieres restarle un entero (6) algo raro ahi, mira revisa esta pregunta [Restar días correctamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/94045/restar-dias-correctamente), en la primera respuesta.

Comment: Dale a editar a la pregunta y agrega ese código también.

Comment: @JoseMgz_Ux ya lo añadi